# how to leave first line and print second line php

Tags: php, explode

i know it can be achieved through explode function but don't know the exact way .

```
<?php
$pizza  = "piece1 piece2 
           piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";

$pieces = explode("<br>", $pizza);

echo $pieces[1]; 
?>
```

the problem is no visible br tag b/w peiece2 and piece3 ....so my question is how in such case how i can detect the second line.

the example is taken from php manuel page

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Did you try with `\n`?

Comment: PHP is not HTML, a new line in a typical PHP file is not `<br>` but, if the file is properly encoded (UTF-8), it is `\n`. so `explode("\n", $string);` or `explode(PHP_EOL, $string);` would be better

Comment: @elias: line breaks have nothing to do with utf. it's entirely an OS thing. windows is `\r\n`, unix is `\n`, etc...

Comment: @MarcB: right you are, it's just that most IDE's I've used on windows convert line breaks to `\n` when you set the encoding to UTF-8. Probably because I've always selected _"Unix UTF-8"_ as my default encoding ;-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explode with the newline escape sequence (`\n`) as a needle:

```
$pizza  = "piece1 piece2 
           piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";

$pieces = explode("\n", $pizza);

echo $pieces[1]; // output: piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6
```

[Playground](http://www.tehplayground.com/#OXzevjUiJ)

Answer (score 4):

First normalize all the line breaks.

```
$pizza = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "<br>", "<br />"), "\n", $pizza);
```

Then do the split:

```
$pieces = explode("\n", $pizza);
```

After that, use `array_slice()` to start from the second line.

```
print_r(array_slice($pieces, 1));
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is failing currently because you're trying to explode on a sub-string (`<br>`) that is not present in your source string, `$pizza`. What IS present, is a line break, so split on that instead.

```
$pizza  = "piece1 piece2 
           piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";

$pieces = explode("\n", $pizza);

echo $pieces[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$pizza  = "piece1 piece2 
           piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";

$pieces = explode(PHP_EOL, $pizza);

echo $pieces[1];
```

live example:
http://codepad.viper-7.com/JIqG99

Comment: Note that `PHP_EOL` on a windows server won't work if your file is UTF-8 encoded. The constant will contain the OS line separator (on windows that is `\r\n`), so it's not guaranteed to work here (Depending on file encoding)